# gradle in eclipse not loading axis2 1.7.0

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, apache-axis

I'm using gradle plugin in my eclipse and in my .gradle file I have dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2', version:'1.7.0'
```

When I do **gradle->Refresh All** I see gradle download axis2 modules but after it's done if I go to **Gradle Dependencies** in my project I don't see anything related to axis2 and yet if I change the version to 1.6.2 it will work. Please point out what am I doing wrong if any.

**EDIT:**
Here is my repositories:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()

    maven { url 'http://10.10.10.22:8081/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local' }
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    maven { url "http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "http://axis2m.sourceforge.net/repo/" }
    maven { url 'http://10.10.10.22:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local' }
```

}

Comment: What does your repositories section look like?

Comment: I edited the post to include them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.apache.axis2:axis2` are the Maven coordinates of the Axis2 all-in-one JAR. As explained in the [1.6.4 release notes](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/release-notes/1.6.4.html), that artifact is no longer available in newer releases. Instead of the all-in-one JAR, you should add dependencies to individual JARs.